# Writing extension for HttpResponse & HttpResponseBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where i would like to write an extension that can be consumed both on HttpResponse & HttpResponseBase.

After some research, found that both are siblings but only by simple extension of the Object class.

And since you can only define a Generic with one specific class i am running into a problem of having to write the same method twice to handle two different object models: Web application redirects and MVC redirects.

Current implementation, although i dont like it:

```
public static void RedirectTo404(this HttpResponseBase response)
{
    response.Redirect("~/404.aspx");
}
public static void RedirectTo404(this HttpResponse response)
{
    response.Redirect("~/404.aspx");
}
```

I would like to have something like this (i know its not syntactically possible, but to give an idea)

```
public static void RedirectTo404<T>(this T response) where T : HttpResponseBase , HttpResponse
{
    response.Redirect("~/404.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net Mvc and what version?

Comment: Not specifically MVC, but i have some projects where we use MVC/EF and ASP.Net/EF.  So it would be nice to have a one stop shop Utility Library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have the `HttpResponse` version delegate to the `HttpResponseBase` version by invoking it with `new HttpResponseWrapper(response)`. That saves you duplicating the code body.

Or have a common method taking a parameter of type dynamic. I would not choose this method though because it is dynamically typed for no good reason.

```
public static void RedirectTo404(this HttpResponseBase response)
{
    response.Redirect("~/404.aspx");
}
public static void RedirectTo404(this HttpResponse response)
{
    RedirectTo404(new HttpResponseWrapper(response)); //delegate to implementation
}
```

Comment: throw an example out so i can see exactly how you envision it.

Comment: Here you go.    _____

Comment: Ok so the Wrapper is used to take a traditional HttpResponse and make it a HttpResponseBase?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what MVC does. MVC gives you the *Base abstractions, not the pure ASP.NET classes.

Comment: sucks that I have to do double implementation though.  Would be nice I could do a single implementation and consume either form.

Comment: The bad news is that that is not possible at the type system level. The good news is that you don't duplicate the implementation. If your method was 10 lines long you wouldn't need to copy them. You just need the stub method.